# Search for multiple sequences within an array

Tags: php

I want to search within an array that I have. The elements to be searched in this array are out of order, their content will be checked only by matching their keys. I could not reach the correct result in a kind of multiple search

```
$array = array(
"31113591" => array("41641105", "56073345", "58624587"),
"67391666" => array("61511566"),
"12337372" => array("00331237")
);

$search1 = array("31113591" => array("41641105", "56073345"), "67391666" => array("61511566")); //true
$search2 = array("31113591" => array("41641105"));  //true
$search3 = array("12337372" => array("00331237"), "67391666" => array("61511566")); //true
$search4 = array("67391666" => array("61511566"), "31113591" => array("56073345")); //true
$search5 = array("31113591" => array("41641105", "56273345"), "67391666" => array("61511566")); //false no in-array matches (56273345)
$search6 = array("31113591" => array("41141105"));  //false no in-array matches (41141105)
$search7 = array("31113591" => array("41641105", "56073345", "58624587", "542425624")); //false no in-array matches (542425624)
```

I want to search $search variable in $array variable I want to get true or false value back

Code i tested myself failed

```
function filter_array_search($array, $search)
{
   $result = false;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
      foreach ($search as $k => $v)
      {         
        if (!isset($array[$k]))
            continue 2;
        else{
            foreach($array[$k] as $fv)
            {
                if(!in_array($fv, $v))
                    continue 3;
            }
        }
      }
      $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question into the form of "I have this data", followed by "I want to search for this thing", and lastly "and I want this result". As it stands this doesn't make much sense. Also, can you show anything that you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your warning, I made the necessary arrangements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it for you.

```php
function search(array $array, array $search) : bool
{
    foreach ($search as $searchKey => $searchArray) {
        // Extra key in the search array is invalid
        if (!array_key_exists($searchKey, $array)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Look for extra items in the search array
        if (count(array_diff($searchArray, $array[$searchKey]))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The test for this code produces 4 true and 3 falses which matches what you provided.

```php
assert(true === search($array, $search1));
assert(true === search($array, $search2));
assert(true === search($array, $search3));
assert(true === search($array, $search4));
assert(false === search($array, $search5));
assert(false === search($array, $search6));
assert(false === search($array, $search7));
```

The [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function is the magic because it:

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

So if there's anything "extra" in the search it will return that, otherwise it returns an empty array

Comment: thanks it works fine. sometimes we look for hard things in simple ones :)